# Win32 app stops receiving mouse events after going full screen and alt-tabbing away

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mouseevent

I'm supporting an older Win32 app that's running DirectX 9, although it's using the Win32 API to handle mouse and keyboard input.

Alt-tabbing away and back works fine while windowed, but if I got full screen and then alt-tab away, the app no longer receives mouse events in its WndPrc function. I'm just doing a borderless full screen window for the change.

Furthermore, when I mouse over the full screen application, I'm receiving cursor changes based on apps behind the app, and when I click, the app disappears and reappears and the mouse events interact with those apps in the back.

The default window style:

```
WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
```

The code for going full screen:

```
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP);
SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, monitor_width, monitor_height, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
```

The messages I receive when I click anywhere over the application (I don't receive any mouse move or mouse hover events):

```
WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING
WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED
WM_NCACTIVATE
WM_GETTEXT
WM_ACTIVATE
WM_NCACTIVATE
WM_GETTEXT
WM_ACTIVATE
WM_ACTIVATEAPP
```

I was suspicious of the position changing events and checked, but the flags SWP_NOSIZE and SWP_NOMOVE were set. Basically, after I receive my last WM_MOUSELEAVE before alt-tabbing or clicking in another application window, that's it when it comes to mouse events.

If I don't leave my application, mouse events continue to work fine in full screen.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in a VS2022 template windows desktop application. Maybe you can try to see if this problem can be reproduced in your template windows desktop application. It would be helpful to troubleshoot if you could provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).